# Why are the changes made to single pointer persists even after the function returns

Tags: c, pointers, tree

I was reading the following article.
[Add greater values of every node](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-greater-values-every-node-given-bst/)

So my doubt after the function `void modifyBSTUtil(struct node *root, int *sum)`

returns , why the changes made by it persist in the tree.

1.We are not using double pointers

2.Nor is the root global

3.We are not returning the address

Can anyone explain why this happens??

**Code**

```
void modifyBSTUtil(struct node *root, int *sum)
{
    // Base Case
    if (root == NULL)  return;

    // Recur for right subtree
    modifyBSTUtil(root->right, sum);

    // Now *sum has sum of nodes in right subtree, add
    // root->data to sum and update root->data
    *sum = *sum + root->data;
    root->data = *sum;

    // Recur for left subtree
    modifyBSTUtil(root->left, sum);
}
```

Call : modifyBSTUtil(root, &sum)

**Insert Function**

```
struct node* insert(struct node* node, int data)
{
    /* If the tree is empty, return a new node */
    if (node == NULL) return newNode(data);

    /* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
    if (data <= node->data)
        node->left  = insert(node->left, data);
    else
        node->right = insert(node->right, data);

    /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
    return node;
}
```

We need to return the address in case of insert function to make changes permanent and why not return here??

Comment: Maybe the pointers are being de-referenced inside of the function.

Comment: Could you give us a [minimal complete exampole](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? (I really should have that hotkeyed.)

Comment: You're not modifying the tree *structure*;  you're modifying the nodes already present. All you need to get there is a root node address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing sacred in a function that prevents is from making a persistent effect on the outside world, the only restriction is the arguments it receives may limit what data it may access.

In this case, it's getting a pointer to a node, and uses it to access the node and change the data there. It's not changing the pointer itself since that is given by value (i.e. - the pointer value is copied, so changing it won't be visible outside), but the pointer value is enough to access the memory of that node and change the values stored there.
Note that accessing the node itself can allow you to change the pointers there, and therefore change the tree structure anywhere *below* that node.

Answer (score 3):

This works because in this example the linking between the nodes is not changed. Only the values they store (`->data`).